# Laravel 5 : change the url which has to send to reset password

Tags: laravel-5, reset-password

I am trying to change the url to reset the password. By default laravel send http://yourdomain.com/password/reset/someEncrptedString

But i want to send link along with locale. i.e. current locale is `en` (en for english)
http://yourdomain.com/en/password/reset/someEncrptedString

How can do this? I have tried to append `App::getlocale()` in action of reset.blade.php `form` url. 
i.e.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo url(App::getLocale().'/password/reset');?>">
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into `Laravel-5` i found my solution with little change in `password.blade.php`

1 - Open `resources/emails/password.blade.php`

2 - replace line

```
Click here to reset your password: {{url(/password/reset/'.$token)}}
```

with

```
Click here to reset your password: <?php echo url(App::getlocale().'/password/reset/'.$token); ?>
```

If any one has better solution than it, then answer it.

Comment: Hi Im also working with tweaking the passwords scaffolding of laravel and im in a pinch. Ive been looking for $token in the email.blade but I dont know where it comes from. help please

Answer (score 0):

If you use laravel5 default PasswordController , there are two ways to fulfill your requirement !

First way:
open the /resources/views/emails/password.blade.php ,  You are free to modify it!

Seconde way :
change reset passwrod link view template in /config/auth.php ,

```html
    'password' => [
        'email' => 'user.link',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
```

then you can create your view template and edit you reset password link !

more detail please click here, http://www.luckybird.me/laravel-reset-password-link.html